# How do I convert a CString into a String with Rust?

Tags: string, rust, type-conversion, c-strings

I have a CString that I'm reading from disk. I created it with [`CStr::from_bytes_until_nul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_bytes_until_nul). My end goal though is to have a `String`, not a `CString`. I'm trying to store my `CString` into a struct that requires `String`. Is there a method to convert from CString to String?

A CString is owned and seems to,

- Guarantee there is no inner `\0`
- Guarantee there is a terminal `\0`

A `String` is also owned. it seems to,

- Guarantee the contents are utf8.

Why isn't there a `.try_into()` from CString to String, that pulls off the terminal `\0` and wraps `str::from_utf8(mycstring)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is method [into_string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.into_string) on `CString` itself, that does exactly what you wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks, weird that this is it's own name.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html) to a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) using [`to_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.to_str) which gives you a [`&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) when successful (e.g. your `CString` contains only valid [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) characters), that can then be converted to a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) by calling [`to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string).

Here is a short sample:

```rust
let cstring = CString::new("A string.").unwrap();
let string = cstring.to_str().unwrap().to_string();
```

and the link to [Rust Explorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#LyoKW2RlcGVuZGVuY2llc10KCiovCnVzZSBzdGQ6OmZmaTo6Q1N0cmluZzsKCmZuIG1haW4oKSB7CiAgICBsZXQgY3N0cmluZzogQ1N0cmluZyA9IENTdHJpbmc6Om5ldygiQSBzdHJpbmcuIikudW53cmFwKCk7CiAgICBsZXQgc3RyaW5nOiBTdHJpbmcgPSBjc3RyaW5nLnRvX3N0cigpLnVud3JhcCgpLnRvX3N0cmluZygpOwogICAgcHJpbnRsbiEoInt9Iiwgc3RyaW5nKTsKfQ==).

Regarding your second question, I see no reason why there should not be a `try_into` conversion, so my speculation is that it simply has not been implemented as of now. There is also an [Open issue on Github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71448) requesting exactly that.

Comment: While this works it by converting to a slice and then to a String you're making a copy, right? Shouldn't this be possible without a copy?

Comment: It shouldn't. `String` knows exactly how many bytes it have to free when it's dropped, but `CString` semantically has to drop one byte more (the terminating zero). So we can't just reuse the allocation from one for another - sizes don't match.

Comment: @Cerberus `String` can hold allocations greater than its length.